# Where can I find economics theories to learn about?

Tags: microeconomics, theory

I'm a beginner to economics so I do not have much knowledge. However, I enjoy learning new economics theories. For now, I normally search for economics theories by looking at those that won nobel prize. Do you know where can I find a list of other economics (particularly microeconomics) theories that don't win the nobel prize?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Consider 'Das Kapital'?

Answer (score 2):

You should read the fundamentals. I strongly suggest two textbooks for microeconomics:

1. Hal Varian - Microeconomics
2. Snyder, Nicholson - Microeconomic Theory

If your read any of the two and find it confusing, I suggest you go for:

3. Mankiw, Taylor - Economics

Comment: +1, one thing I would also add to the first part of the list is Mas-Colell, Whinston and Green Microeconomic Theory - that is literally the most comprehensive microeconomic there is on the market - also it’s critically acclaimed - many consider it a ‘bible’ of microeconomics

Comment: @1muflon1 Mas-Colell, Whinston and Green is an excellent book, but generally considered graduate level.  I wouldn't recommend it for a beginner in economics.

Comment: @AdamBailey that’s true but that’s rather because pre-requisite for it is to have good command mathematics but otherwise it starts literally from the basics. If OP happens to be a physicists interested in learning economics he might already have all the math background required. Also it’s up there with Varian in terms of being graduate text

Comment: I know for a fact that Nicholson is more mathematical than Varian - I've read both of them. As you can tell, the difficulty of the 3 texts I've submitted is scaled.